# Execute a job when node connect itself to Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins server and two nodes. 
I want to execute a basic `ip a` command on a node when it first connect to the Jenkins server.

The problem is that when Node1 connect itself, the job trigger on Node 1 BUT
When Node2 connect to the server, the job trigger AGAIN on Node1...

Can you please help me ?
I use the java client for my nodes and a label called "Julien"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWfg5.jpg

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The question is quite old now, but I was facing same issue and wanted to share my settings to solve it.

I use the [startup trigger plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/startup-trigger-plugin/), as explained above, but by default, it was using any available node to do the job.
In order to make the new connected node run the job, I had to :

- Check "This project is parameterized"
- Add a "Node" parameter with "Name" set to "LAST_STARTED_NODE" (it can be anything else)
- Check "Build when job nodes start"
- In "Advanced", set "Node parameter name" to "LAST_STARTED_NODE" (same as above)

With this configuration, job is run on expected new node.

Comment: I'd like to make clear that the above answer requires the additional [Node and Label parameter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin).

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use the [startup trigger plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Startup+Trigger) which will trigger the jobs on startup of nodes and master. You can also restrict the nodes with there labels for triggering the job.

Also refer [this](https://github.com/jenkinsci/startup-trigger-plugin) link for more info.

I don't know how to select node for executing command but you can create another pipeline job and write pipeline script e.g.

```
pipeline {
    agent {label "${Node parameter name}"}
    stages {
        stage("some stage"){
          steps{
           bat "your command"
         }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi yes I'm using this plugin, that's why I have the box "Build when job nodes start".

Comment: in `Build when job nodes start` option go to advanced setting and use `Node parameter name` option which will send the node name  as parameter with variable you set in `Node parameter name` .

Comment: please have a look at https://imgur.com/a/wFJlvmk 
Did I do something wrong ? As you can see on the last screen, my job trigger because a new node joined the server but the job launch on another node...

Comment: and if I check "Run on all nodes matching the label" the job launch on all my nodes, includng the new one but that's not really a proper way of doing it I think

Comment: check the updated answer. add the value of node parameter which you have added in setting in place of `Node parameter name`